# How to solve General error: 1215 (Cannot add foreign key constraint)

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have the following error on Laravel 5.8 :
**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint**

I read many post on StackOverflow and Laracast on this problem, but I still get the problem.

It works on some case, but not all.

With my reading I found that it would be safer to force on InnoDB.

```php
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

Also I found it use increment on the id table:

```php
$table->increments('id');
```

And to match this with and unsigned integer :

```php
$table->integer('modele_id')->unsigned();
```

Finally I found references to the documentation which lead to some configuration in **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

The foreign is created for modele_id, **but not for option_id**.

Here is the junction table modele_option:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modele_option', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('modele_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('option_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('modele_id')->references('id')->on('modeles');
            $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('options');
        });
    }
```

Table modeles

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modeles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('model_code', 15);
            $table->string('model_descr', 50);
            $table->integer('model_year')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Table options

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code', 10);
            $table->string('libelle', 50);
        });
    }
```

Comment: you may need to add `index()` as well `$table->integer('modele_id')->unsigned()->index();`

Comment: Are the migrations in the correct order? It's hard to create foreign keys if the tables aren't there yet.

Comment: Can you show the full error? Normally MySql gives more information about why it can't create a foreign key.

Comment: I used ```index()``` but I still have the same errors.

The migration which create the foreign keys is at the end.

Comment: please try with `$table->unsignedBigInteger('modele_id');`

Comment: @dparoli I tried, and it didn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem before the problem is when you run `php artisan migrate` laravel migrate each file by order so if your `modeles` table is migrating before `options` table so change the timestamp that the migration file statrs with to make your `options` table before `modeles` table

Comment: It didn't work !

I don't understand !!!
When I add manualy the foreign key, it works, but not with Laravel migration.

My last migration is **option_modele**, and my before last is **modele**.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using **options** table but **additional_items**.

I tried with **options** and it works !

So it mean the convention doesn't allow compound name for table which is not **pivot table**.

For convention my reference is : 
https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions

And it provide an exemple for table with :

> article_comments

It is for that reason I didn't expected it could be the source of the error.